# inotify notifies of a new file wrongly multiple times

Tags: c++, c, linux, boost-thread, inotify

Using inotify to monitor a directory for any new file created in the directory by adding a watch on the directory by

```
    fd = inotify_init();
    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "filename_with_path", IN_CLOSE_WRITE);
    inotify_add_watch(fd, directory_name, IN_CLOSE_WRITE);

    const int event_size = sizeof(struct inotify_event);
    const int buf_len = 1024 * (event_size + FILENAME_MAX);
    while(true) {
        char buf[buf_len];
        int no_of_events, count = 0;
        no_of_events = read(fd, buf, buf_len);
        while(count < no_of_events) {
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *) &buf[count];
            if (event->len) {
                if (event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE) {
                    if (!(event->mask & IN_ISDIR)) {
                         //It's here multiple times 
                    }
                }
            }
            count += event_size + event->len;
        }
```

When I scp a file to the directory, this loops infinitely. What is the problem with this code ? It shows the same event name and event mask too. So , it shows that the event for the same, infinite times.

**There are no break statements**. If I find an event, I just print it and carry on waiting for another event on read(), which should be a blocking call. Instead, it starts looping infinitely. This means, read doesn't block it but returns the same value for one file infinitely.

**This entire operation runs on a separate boost::thread.**

**EDIT:**
Sorry all. The error I was getting was not because of the inotify but because of sqlite which was tricky to detect at first. I think I jumped the gun here. With further investigation, I did find that the inotify works perfectly well. But the error actually came from the sqlite command : `ATTACH`

That command was not a ready-only command as it was supposed to. It was writing some meta data to the file. So inotify gets notification again and again. Since they were happening so fast, it screwed up the application.I finally had to breakup the code to understand why.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this code. Maybe the code you didn't include in the if block uses a `break` statement that skips the `count` variable incrementation ?

Comment: There are no break statements. If I find an event, I just print it and carry on waiting for another event on read(), which should be a blocking call.

Comment: Print the value of `count` after the increment. Does it print what is expected?

Comment: run `strace` on your program when this happens, it might provide more info

Comment: count got incremented fine. It is only the [read] that is giving me the same value again and again forever.

Comment: What does debugging with `gdb` tells you about the values for `count`, `event->len` and `no_of_events`?

Comment: I've just tried your code and I can't reproduce the issues you are having (and I actually tried `scp`). Either the snippet you gave us fails to mention something relevant, or your inotify implementation is broken somehow. Maybe show us how are you initiating inotify? Also, if you *really* don't want to paste the complete code in the post, feel free to PM it.

Comment: I have added how I'm initialising it.
@alk the values for all are fine on the run. Its not about they are not working. My problem it starts looping.

Comment: @King, is this the code exactly as it appears in your program? One possibility I see is that in your actual program, `no_of_events` and `count` are unsigned and the `read` is failing. Then `no_of_events` would have the largest possible value and it is likely that `count` never gets that exact value.

Comment: no, this is exactly the same(no unsigned values) as it is in my application. The only exception being it runs a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code...I'm running basically the same thing and it's working fine. I'm wondering if there's a problem with the test, or some part of the code that's omitted. If you don't mind, let's see if we can remove any ambiguity.

Can you try this out (I know it's almost the same thing, but just humor me) and let me know the results of the exact test?

1) Put the following code into test.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char target[FILENAME_MAX];
   int result;
   int fd;
   int wd;   /* watch descriptor */
   const int event_size = sizeof(struct inotify_event);
   const int buf_len = 1024 * (event_size + FILENAME_MAX);

   strcpy (target, ".");

   fd = inotify_init();
   if (fd < 0) {
      printf ("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      return 1;
   }

   wd = inotify_add_watch (fd, target, IN_CLOSE_WRITE);
   if (wd < 0) {
      printf ("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      return 1;
   }

   while (1) {
     char buff[buf_len];
     int no_of_events, count = 0;

     no_of_events = read (fd, buff, buf_len);

     while (count < no_of_events) {
       struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&buff[count];

       if (event->len){
         if (event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
           if(!(event->mask & IN_ISDIR)){
              printf("%s opened for writing was closed\n", target);
              fflush(stdout);
           }
       }
       count += event_size + event->len;
     }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

2) Compile it with gcc:

```
gcc test.c
```

3) kick it off in one window:

```
./a.out
```

4) in a second window from the same directory try this:

```
echo "hi" > blah.txt
```

Let me know if that works correctly to show output every time the file is written to and does not loop as your code does. If so, there's something important your omiting from your code. If not, then there's some difference in the systems.

Sorry for putting this in the "answer" section, but too much for a comment.

Comment: This entire operation runs inside a c++ application on a separate boost::thread. My code is exactly the same as yours. But just as for your effort, I thought to run it in c. Found the piece to be running correctly. But running on a separate should also run fine. Now that I'm sure that inotify is not broken completely but I'm being tricked because of something. I will dig in and get back with details. Thanks.

Comment: Good to know it wasn't a total waste of time. Since we've established that the underlying inotify functionality is working, if you can provide us some more details of the C++ application running this code perhaps we can help narrow down the issue causing the failure.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that read is returning -1 and since you dont ever try to fix the error, you get another error on the next call to read which also returns -1.

Comment: if read returns -1, then it won't go that far. count(0) < no_of_events(-1) is an epic fail ! It doesn't wait on read, rather it loops. That is my problem.

Comment: @King either the inner loop isnt executed and it simply spins or due to a cast you get MAX_INT and it spins. oh hey, thanks for a -1 for trying to help. much appreciated

Comment: The inner loop is getting executed. and it is also getting after read() multiple times. It shows that the same event occurs multiple times.

Comment: the -1 was not to suggest I don't appreciate you. But this should not be in answer but rather a comment. I already added a comment that I was getting correct values for everything. Ofcourse, I appreciate your time to help others.